# How to merge multiple django south migrations into one migration

Tags: django-south

We use south to manage migrations for a long time, and now we have about 100+ migrations.

It caused a long time to run `python manage.py migrate` on a fresh db.

I'm wonder that whether I can merge all existing migrations to a single one migration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consolidating Django South Migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241648/consolidating-django-south-migrations)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been solved in Django 1.7 + There is a new management command ./manage.py squashmigrations appname , check this link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `squashmigrations` management command to get there. It'll leave the old migration files in place, yet use the squashed version when installing something new.

Example:

```
./manage.py squashmigrations core 0003_auto
```

See [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations)

If you're looking to get rid of all the trial and error waste produced during development, remove the migrations from your apps `migrations` directory along with all mentions of your app in the SQL table `django_migrations` and the apps actual database tables.

Afterwards run `./manage.py makemigrations` and you're good got go. This is not recommended for apps which are already in productive use.

Comment: What does modifying the database itself (as in "… along with all mentions of your app in the SQL table django_migrations") do? During development I ran `makemigrations` to test something, made a small tweak to a field, and then ran it again. Of course I ended up with two migrations which seemed gross for one repository commit. However, just removing the two files and running `makemigrations` (without any cleaning up database mentions) seemed to fix it fine. Or might I have messed up something subtle?